# How do I create a delay with MooTools?

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm more of a jquery guy, and not too familiar with MooTools. I've read up on creating a delay on the MooTools site, but I'm afraid I'm not savvy enough to add it to my script.

After the page loads, I want to add a 300ms delay before this happens:

```
  window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    var data = {};
    var myShow = new Slideshow.delay(1000)('show', null, {controller: true, height: 467, hu: 'half-moon-bay-wedding/', thumbnails: true, width: 730, loop:false});
  });
```

I'm thinking this is probably simple stuff to someone who knows MooTools well? 
Thank you for your help and thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could for instance try:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

  var data = {};
  (function() {
    var myShow = new Slideshow('show', null, {controller: true, height: 467, hu: 'half-moon-bay-wedding/', thumbnails: true, width: 730, loop:false});
  }).delay(300);

});
```

This way, your SlideShow call will be wrapped in an anonymous function, that will be called as soon as the delay of 300 ms has passed.

More info can of course be found in the docs: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Function#Function:delay

Comment: Thank you Luwe, that is right, but I need a way to hide the photos as they load so it didn't have the desired effect. (This is all about trying to make this thing work in IE9--I need the show to load last otherwise it messes up.) Thanks! If have any other ideas, here's the page I'm working on: http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/test/nocurve-moodelay.html

Comment: Hmm, if you want to hide the photos upfront, you will need to do that with CSS first and afterwards make them visible with JavaScript again. Otherwise you will always see the photos because there is a small delay between loading the images and executing JavaScript in a browser.

Comment: Thanks Luwe, but that's a little tricky for me since I'm not too knowledgable about MooTools and that slide show is pretty tricky. Thanks again!